# Is there a possibility to save a video to the gallery when the camera is called with a <input type="file">?

Tags: ios, swift, html

I'm trying to build a hybrid iPhone app that makes use of the  html-tag for video uploads.

Camera opens when the input is clicked, users can record video and upload works fine.

I'm quite new into swift and iOS-development, therefore my question: 
How can I address the video inside the native app part, to additionally store it on the phone inside the gallery? Is this possible?

Comment: May I ask, why this question gets downvotes? I have done several searches on the topic, and I know UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(videoPath: String!,nil, nil,nil). But how do I address the videoPath?

Answer (score 0):

You should use accept="video/mp4,video/x-m4v,video/*"

[MIMEType webkit](https://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebCore/platform/MIMETypeRegistry.cpp)

Comment: accept="video/* is enough to achieve the recording and upload feature, which works fine, as I stated above. I use javascript to find out the temporary filename, now.